# "rejoin" a bash SLURM job

Tags: slurm

Currently, I can use `srun [variety of settings] bash` to create a shell on a compute note. However, if my ssh disconnects for whatever reason and I want to re-access the shell, how can I do that?

Comment: Did you find a solution other than the tmux/screen option suggested by Damien? I have suggested one below which might work.

Answer (score 11):

## Get your job ID

squeue -u $USERNAME

## Get your NodeID

scontrol show job $JOBID | grep NodeList

## Attach (you can assign step = 0)

sattach $JOBID.0

## This did not work for me, but in theory this should work:

srun --pty --jobid $JOBID -w $NODEID /bin/bash

[Source](https://ask.cyberinfrastructure.org/t/how-to-attach-to-a-running-job-to-run-top-on-compute-node/912/2)

Comment: I get "sattach 26641.0" -> "sattach: error: Could not get job step info: Invalid job id specified" even though 26641 is in my squeue. When I run your other command I get "scontrol: invalid option -- 'w'"

Comment: `stattach jobID.0` worked well for my running job, showing the running shell.
However, this can't create a new shell under the same job!

Comment: sattach $JOBID.0 works for me as well and srun doesn't. What does the assign step = 0 do?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the SSH connection from your laptop to the login node of the cluster is unstable, you can use a [terminal multiplexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_multiplexer) such as `screen` or `tmux`, depending on what is already installed on the login node.

Typically, a session would look like this

```
   [you@yourlaptop ~]$ ssh cluster-frontend
   [you@cluster ~]$ tmux # to enter a persistent tmux session
   [you@cluster ~]$ srun [...] bash # to get a shell on a compute node
   [you@computenode ~]$ # some work, then...
   some SSH error (e.g. Write failed: Broken pipe)
   [you@yourlaptop ~]$ ssh cluster-frontend
   [you@cluster ~]$ tmux a # to re-attach to the persistent tmux session
   [you@computenode ~]$ # resume work
```

With `screen`, you would use `screen -r` rather than `tmux a`. Otherwise the process is the same.

If you want to join a job from another terminal instance (on the right below), you can use the  Slurm's `sattach` command.

```
[you@yourlaptop ~]$ ssh cluster-frontend           |  
[you@cluster ~]$ srun [...] bash                   |
srun: job ******* queued and waiting for resources |
srun: job ******* has been allocated resources     | [you@yourlaptop ~]$ ssh cluster-frontend
[you@computenode ~]$                               | [you@cluster ~]$ sattach --pty ********
[you@computenode ~]$ echo OK                       | [you@computenode ~]$ echo OK
[you@computenode ~]$ OK                            | [you@computenode ~]$ OK
```

The original terminal and the one in which `sattach` was run are now entirely synchronised.

Note that the above does not protect from an accidental termination of `srun`; whenever `srun` terminates, the job is terminated as well.

Comment: Thanks for that! However, it's not just a stability issue. For instance, if I open a job on one terminal, is there a way to join it from another iterm instance?

Comment: @ThirtyOneTwentySeven, yes, you can have more than one tmux client attached to the same session at a time.

Comment: In my case I was using `tmux`, but today I logged in and all my tmux sessions had been killed. Maybe the frontend server had been restarted or something. The jobs are still running, it seems from running `squeue`. I wonder if I can still connect to their output somehow? Or I have to restart them, wasting 24 hours of work...

Comment: @ThomasAhle Check you logged into the same server as you were using tmux on earlier. Gets tricky with HPC as the same url can redirect to multiple servers. Check the command prompt.